# How to navigate quickly to my installed packages?

Tags: package, navigation

When I'm in the package manager (`M-x package-list-packages`), I'd like to quickly navigate to my installed packages.

[image: emacs packages]

There are literally thousands of packages marked as *available*, *installed*, or *built-in*, but all of the navigation appears to be line-by-line.  Is this an oversight with the package manager or am I overlooking something obvious (aside from basic string search, of course)?

Comment: There is a `Filter package list option`, you can invoke it by pressing `f` or the function `package-menu-filter`.

Comment: @KingShimkus: I'm running the standard package manager that comes with emacs 24.3.1 which doesn't appear to have package-menu-filter, but thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Oh, sorry I couldn't of been of more assistance.

Comment: If you find that some feature, whether convenience or vital, is missing or wrong in the Emacs package system, consider reporting it for improvement, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. (That is for enhancement requests, as well as bugs.)

Comment: Jeff Bauer: If you update to Emacs 24.4 that `f` key filter function will be available.

Comment: `f` is only for filtering on keyword, not status.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tend to end up using *occur* (or more specifically *helm-swoop*) to narrow down my choices.

However you can also use [paradox](https://github.com/Malabarba/paradox), which extends the functionality of the basic package manager. This include <kbd>S x</kbd> sorting options as well as single key next and status. It also has its own filter options: notably, <kbd>f u</kbd> will narrow down to all packages affected by an upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option, if you just want to use `completing-read` (perhaps with `ido` via `ido-everywhere` or `ido-ubiquitous`) to quickly open an installed package outside of the package list:

```
(defun open-package ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((packages (mapcar 'symbol-name (mapcar 'car package-alist)))
         (package (completing-read "Open package: " packages nil t)))
    (find-library package)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Emacs, you can access the package view with `M-x` `list-packages`. You can then filter the packages:

- by upgradable with `/` `u`;
- by any other status (available, dependency, disabled, etc) with `/` `s`;
- by name with `/` `n`;
- by description with `/` `d`;

And then clear the filter with `/` `/`.

The invoked commands are all in the `package-menu-filter-*` family, which you can explore for more options.

So to answer the original question, the way to display all installed packages is:
`/` `s` `installed` `RET`.